# Can't find Steam in Ububtu Software Center

Tags: steam

I am having a problem. I cannot find Steam on Ubuntu Software Center. I was able to find it before I installed Ubuntu, but now I am not able to find it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Just open the software centre and enter `steam` in to the search box.

Comment: I did that and it doesn't find it.

Comment: Do you mean to say you weren't able to find it after an upgrade?

Comment: Right. I was test driving Ubuntu from a thumb drive and was able to find and install Steam. Now that I have installed Ubuntu and not running from the thumb drive I can't find Steam in the Software Center. Not sure what else I can do outside of manually installing it.

Answer (score 3):

Open the .deb file directly from steam's website and it will open the software centre, even when it's already installed.

### here is the link:

http://media.steampowered.com/client/installer/steam.deb

Comment: I hope this answer was helpful to you, if it was, please vote up and accept :-)

Comment: Two years later and this answer definitely helped me.

Comment: Glad to read this is still helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

Steam is available in the official repository only for Ubuntu 12.04. So you'll have to [download](http://media.steampowered.com/client/installer/steam.deb) it and install it seperately